# Gradle build fails for some reasons unknown to me

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, apache-beam

Gradle version is 7.6.1 on my mac and JVM version is 11 and the build file is shown here and I have shared the log file in google drive under the link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZpyvEJ-5WeL8XWJzfK1jq2P04X-jeGh/view?usp=share_link

this is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless"

group = "com.comxxx.merch.item.cache"
archivesBaseName = "merch-ic-batch-dataflow"
version = "1.0.0"

if (System.getenv("USE_PROXY") != null) {
    System.setProperty('http.proxyHost', 'thd-svr-proxy-qa.comxxx.com')
    System.setProperty('http.proxyPort', '7070')
    System.setProperty('http.nonProxyHosts', '*.comxxx.com|localhost')

    System.setProperty('https.proxyHost', 'thd-svr-proxy-qa.comxxx.com')
    System.setProperty('https.proxyPort', '7070')
    System.setProperty('https.nonProxyHosts', '*.comxxx.com|localhost')
}

buildscript {
    if (System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER") != null && System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PASS") != null) {
        project.ext.set("artifactory.username", System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER"))
        project.ext.set("artifactory.password", System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PASS"))
    }
    ext["groovy.version"] = "2.5.13"
    ext {
        lombokVersion = "1.18.10"
        beamVersion = "2.47.0"
        clientLibVersion = '0.72.0'
        logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
        jacksonVersion = "2.15.0"

        mainClassName = "com.comxxx.merch.item.cache.batch.ProcessDiscrepancyItems"

        dataflowNetwork = "--network=internal"
        dataflowSubnetwork = "--subnetwork=regions/us-east1/subnetworks/backend-us-east1-subnet"
        dataflowProject = "--project=${project.findProperty("dataflowGcpProject")}"
        dataflowRegion = "--region=us-east1"
        dataflowRunner = "--runner=DataflowRunner"
        dataflowTemplateLocation = "--templateLocation=gs://${project.findProperty("dataflowGcpProject")}-cache-dataflow/${rootProject.name}/templates/${rootProject.name}"
        dataflowTempLocation = "--tempLocation=gs://${project.findProperty("dataflowGcpProject")}-cache-dataflow/${rootProject.name}/temp"
        dataflowStagingLocation = "--stagingLocation=gs://${project.findProperty("dataflowGcpProject")}-cache-dataflow/${rootProject.name}/staging"
        dataflowServiceAccount = "--serviceAccount=mic-item-event-publisher-sa@${project.findProperty("dataflowGcpProject")}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        dataflowNumWorkers = "--numWorkers=1"
        dataflowMaxNumWorkers = "--maxNumWorkers=1"
        dataflowWorkerMachineType = "--workerMachineType=n2-standard-8"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        if (project.hasProperty('artifactory.username') && project.hasProperty('artifactory.password')) {
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/libs-release'
                credentials {
                    username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                    password = project.property('artifactory.password')
                }
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot'
                credentials {
                    username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                    password = project.property('artifactory.password')
                }
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins'
                credentials {
                    username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                    password = project.property('artifactory.password')
                }
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
        }
        maven {
            url = 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:4.3.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    if (project.hasProperty('artifactory.username') && project.hasProperty('artifactory.password')) {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/libs-release'
            credentials {
                username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                password = project.property('artifactory.password')
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot'
            credentials {
                username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                password = project.property('artifactory.password')
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.artifactory.comxxx.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins'
            credentials {
                username = project.property('artifactory.username')
                password = project.property('artifactory.password')
            }
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://packages.confluent.io/maven/'
    }
}

configurations {
    testCompile
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '3.0.2.RELEASE'

    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:${beamVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:${beamVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:${beamVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:${beamVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-secretmanager:1.2.0"
    implementation platform("com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-bom:${clientLibVersion}")
    implementation "com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:assortment-client-http"
    implementation "com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support-http"
    implementation "com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons"
    implementation "com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api"
    implementation "com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-common"

    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}"

    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"

    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec', version: '4.1.52.Final'
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec-http', version: '4.1.52.Final'

    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.4'

    testImplementation "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.16"

    testImplementation "org.objenesis:objenesis:3.1"

    testImplementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2"
}

task getDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    into "build/dependencies"
}

test {
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        logger.quiet "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }

    finalizedBy {
        jacocoTestReport
        getDependencies
    }
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDir file("src/test/groovy")
        }
    }
}

build {
    dependsOn {
        clean
        spotlessApply
    }
}

spotless {
    enforceCheck false
    java {
        importOrder "com", "org", "javax", "java"
        eclipse().configFile("${project.rootDir}/java_format.xml")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [])
        }))
    }
}

task stageDataflow(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn {
        processMetadata
    }
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = project.findProperty("mainClassName")
    jvmArgs = project.hasProperty("useProxy") ? ['-Dhttp.proxyHost=thd-svr-proxy-qa.comxxx.com','-Dhttp.proxyPort=7070','-Dhttps.proxyHost=thd-svr-proxy-qa.comxxx.com','-Dhttps.proxyPort=7070'] : []
    args(
            [
                    dataflowNetwork,
                    dataflowSubnetwork,
                    dataflowProject,
                    dataflowRegion,
                    dataflowRunner,
                    dataflowTemplateLocation,
                    dataflowTempLocation,
                    dataflowStagingLocation,
                    dataflowServiceAccount,
                    dataflowNumWorkers,
                    dataflowMaxNumWorkers,
                    dataflowWorkerMachineType
            ]
    )
    doLast {
        delete fileTree("src/main/resources/").matching({include "*_metadata"})
    }
}

task processMetadata(type: Copy) {
    from "src/main/resources"
    include "*_template.json"
    into "src/main/resources"
    expand([releaseVersion: project.findProperty("releaseVersion") ?: version])
    rename {it - ~/_template\.json$/}
    doLast {
        println "processed metadata file"
    }
}
```

Refer to the above gdrive for the complete log and the first error I see starts with this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0.
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0
         project : > com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0 > com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0
         project : > org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0 > org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-expansion-service:2.47.0 > com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.0
         project : > com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support-http:0.72.0 > com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.15.0
         project : > org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0 > com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.15.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:assortment-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-kafka:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.47.0' (runtime)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-expansion-service:2.47.0' (runtime)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:5.0.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0' (platform-runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Constraint path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-common:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.fortify:fortify-bom:0.17.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:{strictly 2.13.0; reject [0.0.0, 2.13.0)}'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:couch-support-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:catalog-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:catalog-client:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:pricing-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:pricing-client:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-kafka:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:5.3.2' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.10.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-expansion-service:2.47.0' (runtime)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.15.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.15.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.5'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.1' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:catalog-client:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-support:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'

   > Could not resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0.
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0 > com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.47.0' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:assortment-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0' (platform-runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0'
           Constraint path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:client-common:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.fortify:fortify-bom:0.17.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:{strictly 2.13.0; reject [0.0.0, 2.13.0)}'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.thd.monarch:monarch-cache-model:3.1.6' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.1'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache.model:merch-ic-data-models-lib:0.44.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:catalog-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-commons:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:pricing-client-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
           Dependency path 'com.comxxx.merch.item.cache:merch-ic-batch-dataflow:1.0.0' --> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:item-client-api:0.72.0' (runtimeElements)
--> 'com.comxxx.merch.ic.client:couch-support-http:0.72.0' (runtimeElements) --> 'com.thd.monarch:monarch-cache-client:3.1.6' (runtime) --> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.1'
```

Comment: Tried but getting an error
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud:2.47.0.
     Searched in the following locations:

Comment: "_Tried but_" -- No, @guillaumeblaquiere wasn't suggesting a fix to your problem, but rather was stating the [tag:google-cloud-platform] tag you added to _your question_ was erroneously present (and they removed it).

Answer (score 2):

The important part of the message is this line:

```
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind' that satisfies the version constraints:
```

This says that gradle cannot figure out which version of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` to use. If you copy this name and search for it in the message, you will see at least three different versions that gradle wants to use and it cannot figure out which of those to choose. This happens when you declare a dependencies `A` and `B` and `B` also declares a dependency on `A`, but the versions don't match.

One solution might be to remove the explicit dependency `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` entirely since other dependencies already pull it in. Otherwise, you will need to figure out a version that will satisfy all of the constraints declared by each of your other dependencies. You may also need to modify the version of these other dependencies.